# Is there a way to close tab opened by a script from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, api, iframe

I have added an iframe to my webpage that is used for converting video links to mp3 format.
iframe shows a button that, when clicked, opens a new tab before starting to download the wanted mp3 file. I would like to know if there is a way in javascript to close that newly opened tab to ensure a better user experience. I know that `window.close()` can do that, but not sure if we can apply that to a tab opened by a script from an iframe.

This is the iframe in question, It sends a get request to the link specified in the src attribute.

```
<iframe id="downloadIframe" src="https://loader.to/api/button/?url=${vidLink}&f=mp3&color=0964D3"></iframe>
```

When the iframe is loaded, you can see this in the code it loads with it:

```
<a id="downloadButton" onclick="onClick();window.open('https://loader.to/ajax/a.php');" href="#">
```

I believe that the opened window is caused by `window.open()`.
Knowing that I cant change the code that is within an iframe, any idea how I can close that tab?

Comment: Only the script that opened a window or tab can close it.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't distinguish between windows and tabs. All the window operations will operate on either.

Comment: yes I know that only the script that opened a window or tab can close it. I would like to know If there is something we can do to bypass that in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Open the dowlnoad in a iframe instead of a tab.

Then you can later drop the iframe from the DOM making it disappear.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by open the download in a ifram. can you please elaborate?

Comment: `<iframe src="downloadURL">`

Comment: the src attribute in the iframe is already filled.  if the iframe is dropped after it is clicked, that wont close the newly opened tab since by then the script that opens would have already done so.

Answer (score 0):

you can block the iframe from opening new tabs by using the sandbox attribute.
`sandbox=""`
Sandbox Applies extra restrictions to the content in the frame. The value of the attribute can either be empty to apply all restrictions or space-separated tokens to lift particular restrictions.
You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)